# How to approach OpAmp analysis when V(+) has a resistance has a single resistor

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

The question states to find Load Current IL. Through VEP V(+)=V(-) I wanted to find Voltage at the (+'ve inverting input). However, I cant use traditional voltage divider or KCL to find it because theres only 1 resistor. In addition, Ideal opamp states that no current flows through these inputs. So how do I calculate the voltage at the inputs for this question?

My first initial attempt was looking at the inverting input (-'ve) input and I can see that the voltage node is 5V and used KCL at node connecting iL.

I also noticed that because the left wire connecting the output voltage (V out) has no resistance, the current has to = 0 in accordance to Ohms law. (V / 0 = infinite current)

But I got 4.54 mA which was not correct. The answer was 15 mA. What did I do wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What is 10 V - (0 amps x 1 k)?

Comment: Is a current through the 10k necessary for feedback? If not, then one can suppress the resistor(s) ...

Comment: @Antonio51 The resistor has to be there to make the voltage across it zero. With an ideal op-amp you could use a 1\$\Omega\$ resistor or a 1G\$\Omega\$ resistor and the result would be the same. With a real op-amp it will work fine with a resistor of xx k\$\Omega\$ or less (probably xxx k\$\Omega\$  but if the resistor is too high bad things (offset, maybe oscillation) will start to show up. In either case you could short the resistors out and the result would be the same (ideal) or very similar (real).

Comment: Ok. It was just a suggestion for OP ... to found immediately the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is stated that there is no bias current from the op-amp so you know the left 1K resistor and the 10K resistor have no voltage across them.

Secondly, you know that (when in balance) the op-amp inputs will have the same potential. The op-amp output (assuming negative feedback) will try to drive to a voltage to make that condition true.

Hint: Calculate the op-amp output voltage required for that to be true.

Comment: Only true if power supply is at least ... +20V ?

Comment: @Antonio51 sure. But this looks like a problem from a textbook, and the power supply isn't even shown.

Comment: @Antonio51 It's an ideal op-amp so it doesn't even need a power supply. But sure, a real op-amp might need two or three volts more than the +15 it has to supply at the output for the V+ supply.

Comment: Ok. One must then assume that if ... this is an ideal op amp, then the output voltage is irrelevant of power supplies. Question to be updated?